# C# Combine thousands of images into one file, pull individual images for ImageList

Tags: c#, imagelist

I'm writing an application that creates an image list on the fly from a folder with over 9000 image files, based on the images file name. Each time my ListView is updated it generates a fresh ImageList (I think this helps keep memory usage down).

The large amount of files creates many obvious issues, especially when new images are added.  I'm wondering if there is any way I can create one large file that contains all of these images, and still dynamically create an image list based on the images (old?) file name.

Thanks!

Comment: Millions of different ways, I suppose.  Maybe you can, on first run, build your imagelist and store the filenames. A dictionary?  Then, use directorynotification or I believe .NET has a component called FileSystemWatcher.  It detects a new or modified file, have it update your imagelist.  If an image has been updated, you can pull this dictionary and see what index, the "old" image is at, remove it, and re-add the "new" image.

Comment: I'm hoping to prevent having to ship the thousands of images with the distributable.  I was hoping there was a way to combine all the images into one file, and create imagelists from that file.

Comment: Boy that's a tough one.  Without storing images as BLOBS in a database or something.  Maybe look into creating a collection of objects and having each image stored in a object of that collection and then ** serialize ** the collection out to a file.  You still need a way to know, when new images are added to a directory.  If one is, your system adds a new object with the loaded image to your collection and you save that collection out again.  Having a collection, you can iterate over it and look for a specified image, build a new imagelist based off it, etc ...

Comment: Why don't you save your image in database like Sql as usual?

Comment: You are not going to look at 9000 images all at the same time.  Using paging to keep this in check, look at the way Google does it for inspiration.